# Chrome Device mode- cannot see the Viewport controls

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Running Chrome 66.0.3359.170 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 8.1

I can see the Device Mode toggle button in the dev tools window and can toggle it on and off but I cannot see the Viewport controls or anything resembling a Device mode menu bar.

Can someone tell me where it should be so I can first verify whether it is missing or I am just a little slow. Or whether I have to enable a particular menu bar or something.

Referring to the menu shown in the first image on this page-
[Test Responsive and Device-specific Viewports](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports#media-queries)

[image]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Face the same issue following steps help me

1. Inspect the window / open DevTools
2. Select 'Customize & control DevTools' option from the right top (indicated by 3 vertical dots).
3. select 'setting'
4. click on 'Restore Default and reload'

Comment: Another issue with emulator screen size make it wide enough & you see viewport control.